# How to create controller object and execute action with parameter from global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, global-asax

I have this code in `global.asax`

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");

            IController controller = new Controllers.HomeController();
            controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));

        }
```

how can I add parameter to Action method / RouteData ? I would like to show exception message to the user.

Comment: Why do you want to call the controller method on error, instead call the service or the business logic from Application Error?

Comment: do you mean to process error and return a view directly from global.asax ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do with application error block, want to log error or make database call to log error?

Comment: I am already logging the error to the database in the `Application_Error` but I want to show an error page to the user with the basic description of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figure it out,

```
routeData.Values.Add("message", exception.Message);
```

and in action just catch that parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(string message)
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the custom error page you need to change the web.config.

`<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>`

You can create error pages for different status code.

Make sure you have controller and action method to return view.

After Application_error MVC it self will redirect to the same page as described in web.config.

Please refer this [link](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages) for more information.

Comment: In this case, how can I access the error exception in the action ?

Comment: The exception will be accessed at the Application_error level, the .net will redirect to the action described in the config file. The action should only return view

Comment: but how can I display the error description (exception message) in the view ?